# Regular Expression Matching the below conditions

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular Expression:
to find if the string starts with a string followed by comma, or comma followed by string followed by comma or comma followed by string at the end of the string

`string, or ,string, or ,string`.

I have tried this but isnt working:

```
^[,]string[,]$
```

and

```
/^(?:\,string\,)$/
```

Comment: Comma is not a meta-character in `regex`. There is no need to escape it or protect it in any way (like putting it into a character range).

Comment: Try [`^(?=.*,),?string,?$`](https://regex101.com/r/s0MQ7z/1).

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Your `regex`es do not work because they do not match the description. The text clearly says one of the two commas can be missing but your `regex`es require the comma on both the start and the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion didnt worked

Comment: @mlibby i am using java

Comment: Use an alternation [`^,?string,.*$|^.*,string$`](https://regex101.com/r/T3Lh8s/1)

Comment: @axiac how should i reform the regex? any suggestions please?

Comment: First of all it should be very clear to you what should the `regex` match. Then you describe the requirement clearly so any reader could understand it. Example input strings and the expected output always help. Then you'll get more answers (or suggestions in comments) than you can handle. This is how it usually happens on [so]. The requirements are not clear now, at least not clear for me.

Comment: Judging by the answer, my example regex above must work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you'll settle for a true result in any of these three cases, i.e. that you don't need to differentiate between which case was true regarding where the commas actually appeared.

If you don't need to extract the "string" value that was matched, then this should work:

```
^(,string|,string,|string,)$
```

( | ) is an OR construct.

If you do want to extract the string matched using a capture, then the following should work

```
^(,(\w+)|,(\w+),|(\w+),)$
```

and your matched string will be captured as match group 2, 3, or 4.  Obviously I'm making some assumptions about what's allowed to appear in the "string" value here ( = \w+ = only one or more alphanumerics and underscores), but you should be able to modify that part of the regexp if you need to.

I experimented with this using a Rubular test at http://rubular.com/r/qyGGjHcC59 .  If there's a Java-equivalent RE test tool somewhere, use that instead, but probably not needed since this is a pretty standard part of RE that you're using here.